# Backbone navigate triggers twice in Firefox

Tags: firefox, backbone.js, url-routing

Trying to use Backbone's navigate property.

```
 this.navigate("week/" + companyName + "/" + employeeNo + "/" + weekEnd, { trigger: true, replace: false });
```

The code above is executed once.

It hits this:

```
routes: {
    "week/:companyName/:employeeNo/:weekEnd": "getWeek"
},
```

And then this function gets hit twice:

```
getWeek: function (companyName, employeeNo, weekEnd) {
    console.log('getWeek:', companyName, employeeNo, weekEnd);
 }
```

It is logged twice in Firefox, only once in IE and Chrome.

What's the issue here? I originally didn't even have trigger set to true, and Firefox ignored that and still triggered the URL.

Comment: You should step through the code with the unminified backbone source, specifically look for when `loadUrl` is being called and what it calls as that is what runs the callbacks.

Comment: I also find Backbone.js navigation triggers differently in Firefox vs Chrome + Safari on Mac, and haven't figured that out either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar issue recently with Firefox doing two server calls after a Backbone.navigate. In my case it was because we had not encoded the string. Does your company name have any characters which should be encoded?

You could try:

```
this.navigate("week/" + escape(companyName) + "/" + employeeNo + "/" + weekEnd, { trigger: true, replace: false });
```

Comment: I have run into this problem before as well, and the fix had to do with encoding.

Comment: Same thing happens with diacritics: http://jsfiddle.net/adyz/qcged76e/2/ what do you think about that? @AdamLockhart?

Answer (score 4):

Stepping in as I've run into the same issue and got to the underlying problem here.

As everyone mentioned before, the problem comes from URL encoding. Now as to why the issue only appears in Firefox...

Let's start by summarizing quickly how the routes are called when the hash changes. There are 3 key functions here:

- **loadUrl**: this function is the one that will call your route handler.
- **navigate**: this is the function used to change the route manually. If the *trigger* flag is set to *true*, the function will call *loadUrl*.
- **checkUrl**: this function is set as callback for the *onhashchange* event on the *window* object (when it's available of course). It also runs *loadUrl* on certain conditions.

Now, we're getting to the interesting part.

When you run **navigate**, Backbone will cache the fragment you navigated to. The hash changing, **checkUrl** will also be called. This function will then check if the cached hash equals the current one, so as not to execute **loadUrl** if you called **navigate** before, because it would mean it has already been called. To make that comparison, **checkUrl** gets the current hash with the function **getFragment**, which uses **getHash**. Here is **getHash**'s code:

```
getHash: function(window) {
  var match = (window || this).location.href.match(/#(.*)$/);
  return match ? match[1] : '';
},
```

And you got your problem. *location.href* is URI-encoded in firefox, but is not in chrome. So if you navigated to another hash (**with or without** the *trigger* flag), in firefox, Backbone will cache the unencoded version of your hash, and then compare it with the encoded version. If your hash contained a should-be-encoded character, the result of the comparison will be negative, and Backbone will execute the route handler it should not execute.

As per the solution, well, folks said it before, your URIs should be encoded.

Comment: Hey @Loamhoof, I have a similar problem too, but this time in Safari on Mac. here you can find the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/adyz/qcged76e/2/ -- Basically, I think it's because of diacritics. -- encoded or not. If you click on the second link, the url is decoded by the route function. Thanks a ton

Comment: It's on Safari too.

Comment: Hi @AdrianFlorescu. I encourage you to fiddle with Backbone's code to see what's wrong, more specifically the aforementioned `checkUrl` function which probably holds the key to your problem. This response has been written some time ago (Backbone 1.0 I think), but it seems this part of Backbone's code hasn't changed much since then: http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-232. Good luck and please post your findings if you solve your problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

Question may be old, but for me this was still relevant. Encoding the url wasn't enough in my case. I replaced the GetHash() function in Backbone with:

```
getHash: function (t) { 
    var e = (t || this).location.href.match(/#(.*)$/);
    return match ? this.decodeFragment(match[1]) : '';
}
```